# c# Regex replace everything not in specific UTF-8 character set ranges (whitelist)

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to only include the non-printable characters specific to this Latin character set: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x

My regex looks like this:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\u0020-\u007E]|[^\u00A0-\u00FF]", string.Empty);
```

I have a problem with the LINE SEPARATOR' (u2028) specifically, but I want to exclude any control character as well, so I wanted a whitelist, rather than a blacklist.

I'm basically trying to include only u0020 (SPACE) through to u007E (TILDE) or u00A0 (NO-BREAK SPACE) through to u00FF (LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS).

I've got my negation wrong on the sets, but I can't figure out how to solve it. Any ideas?

## UPDATE

The following appears to work

```
var input = "</span><span>     </span><span>"
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\u0020-\u007E\u00A0-\u00FF]", string.Empty);
// gives: </span><span>    </span><span>
```

Example working: http://rextester.com/YCIWTN86420

Comment: Use `\p{C}`, or `\p{Cc}`.

Comment: If the above does not work, please clarify by adding examples of what you need to match. Note that matching all the chars marked as `<control>` in the table you linked to, it is really not an issue, you may add them to the character class, `[\u0000-\u001F\007F-\u009F]`.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, those are the exact characters I don't want, but to be safe I only want to include the characters that are in the set described above. I think I have figured it out. I think it is [^\u0020-\u007E\u00A0-\u00FF].

Comment: Why do you think so? Please post a sample string and the expected output. Right now, your question is asked in such a way that only you can answer it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please see update. It appears to have solved my problem.

Comment: I tried your code, but it did not compile. Making `input` a verbatim string literal does not result in what you need (see [demo](http://ideone.com/bI8r3E))

Comment: Let's recap: you want to remove all control symbols from the range defined in the table the link to which you shared? *BUT* `\u2028` is not from that range. *AND* you need to also remove spaces? Your question is not at all clear and the sample string/expected bahavior does not match them. Try [`Regex.Replace(input, @"[\p{C}\s]", string.Empty)`](http://ideone.com/OaBqAz).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to WHITELIST the characters in the sets listed. I'm not trying to EXCLUDE characters, but INCLUDE them. Hence the NOT ^. Basically "replace all characters NOT in this pattern with an empty string". I.e. It's a whitelist and not a blacklist. The regex above in the edit works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest you remove the question since 1) it is unclear 2) the solution does not work, for some reason, it only works for you - > won't be helpful for anyone.

Comment: It works fine: http://rextester.com/TDQYE66188

Comment: But the spaces are not removed. You posted expected behavior as `// gives: </span><span></span><span>`

Comment: I was quite specific above. I want to *keep* everything that is in the sets described, and drop everything else. SPACE (u0020) is in the set, so it should be kept.